# it is not possible to reset input value for typeahead component

Tags: angular, angular6, ng-bootstrap, typeahead

For the typeahead component, it seems that is not possible to clear the input value after the results list appears. If the results list doesn't appear, the model can be cleared from a button without problem.

Steps to reproduce:

1. open https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rybwwn-w3w4ca
2. introduce text "aaa"
3. click on button "Clear"
4. the input is cleared
5. introduce text "ala". The result list appears.
6. click on button "Clear"
7. the input is not cleared

is there another way to clear the input value?

Answer (score 0):

### Fix 1 : Use the setTimeout

```
clear(){
   setTimeout(()=>{
       this.model = '';
     });
  }
```

### Fix 2 : Use Native elmenent

You can leverage `ElementRef` and `ViewChild` to get the reference for `search input` and clear the text value by native reference of it.

Your modified version of your `clear` method is -

```
import {Component, ElementRef, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';

clear(){
    this.model = '';
    console.log(this.searchInput.nativeElement);
    setTimeout(()=>{
       this.searchInput.nativeElement.value = "";
    }) 
  }
```

working copy is here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rybwwn-hxpcyv

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your solution works. But do you know why if the value is set without timeout your code doesn't work?

Comment: Its because if your TypeAhead  is opened and you try to click on the clear button no change detection is running and Angular is not aware of it. To ensure that its part of next change detection we use setTimeOut.  Updated the answer with another solution.

Comment: You can accept the answer if it meets your requirement.